# Processing button on a Show view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application entity called Source on my app. This entity has a property called url.

I want to make a processing on my SHOW view. So I added a button on the show view to make a call to my controller and do this processing.

This is my routes.rb

```
  get '/process', to: 'sources#read', as: 'read'
```

This is my controller method:

```
class SourcesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_source, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :read]
  access all: [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy, :read], user: :all
def read
    require 'rss'
    require 'open-uri'
    url = @source.url
    open(url) do |rss|
      feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
      puts "Title: #{feed.channel.title}"
      feed.items.each do |item|
        puts "Item: #{item.title}"
        puts "Link: #{item.link}"
        puts "Description: #{item.description}"
      end
    end
    render template: 'rss_reader/home'
  end
```

And of course. My show.html.erb:

```
<%= button_to 'Process Source', read_path(@source), method: :get %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_source_path(@source) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', sources_path %>
</div>
```

When I press the "Process Source" button, it goes to the right controller method, but the object @source its not being found because of:

```
Couldn't find Source with 'id'=
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_source
  @source = Source.find(params[:id])
end
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the output of `rake routes | grep read`?

Comment: Do you have any before filters for action `read`? Include them in question, if you do.

Comment: Jagdeep. I get your idea and change in the question the description. The error now changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are visiting the route with `read_path(@source)` which is *expected* to set the param `id` to the value `@source.id`, but you **did not** define your routes to support any parameter in the path.

I believe `read` is an action that belongs to a single instance of `Source`. So, you should [define the route on member](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes). This way you will be able to access `params[:id]` in your controller and your before_action `set_source` will work fine.

Change your route definition to:

```
resources :sources, only: [...] do    # Keep the `only` array just as you have now.
  get '/process', to: 'sources#read', as: 'read', on: :member
end
```

Comment: Updated the answer with explanation.